# I'm having trouble with the box; my friend says he has to scroll to see the box

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with the box. On my screen it looks good, but  soon my friend says he has to scroll to see the box.
Here is the code. What am I doing wrong? How can I make it responsive for mobile?

```
.three{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:420px;
  width:280px;
  margin-top:-390px;
  margin-left:1100px;
  background-image:url(https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/16112073_395630670772700_1781030081_n.jpg?oh=8c322f4e2cf22c38fa6b20744e28b378&oe=587F0976);
  box-shadow:10px 10px #000;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}
```

https://codepen.io/iDarknesskiller/pen/qRavGy

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem! Maybe his screen is smaller so the content breaks into a second line. For mobile support use % rem and media queries (just google it)